# IntelliJ Ant Build Window Missing

Tags: intellij-idea

I've been working on a project in IntelliJ and now when I decided to add Ant support I realised that the Ant Build Window is missing. I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 but I doubt it makes any difference. Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 10.5 and it works just fine. Even without having `build.xml` file I can open that window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and searching for *Ant Build*.

If you are missing this option you probably don't have installed/enabled *Ant support* plugin. Check out *File* -> *Settings* -> *Plugins*.

Answer (score 4):

Please check that Ant plug-in in enabled in `Settings` | `Plugins`.